# Unbound config to forward unknow local subdomain name

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, dns-zone, unbound

I am currently on a local aera network where no loop-back is allowed meaning that I cannot reach my public IP address from the local network.

Several services need to be migrated in my local area network whilst keeping the domain name because we need to reach our services both from an external access and also while connected locally. To achieve this, we set up an internal DNS server with `Unbound`. This works well with full domain names and subdomains that are known from our team.

The problem we have is that when a subdomain is unknown, we need this subdomain to reach outside the local area network. We can achieve this by manually setting up each needed subdomains but this is not possible because we have a lot of them now and for the future.

So the question is: **is it possible to make unknown subdomain reach an external DNS server and how?**

Here is the `Unbound` configuration:

```
server:
    verbosity: 1
    interface: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    port: 53
    do-ip4: yes
    do-ip6: no
    do-udp: yes
    do-tcp: yes
    access-control: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24 allow
    hide-identity: yes
    hide-version: yes
    harden-glue: yes
    harden-dnssec-stripped: yes
    use-caps-for-id: yes
    do-not-query-localhost: no
    private-address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24
    private-domain: "domain.com"
    local-zone: "domain.com." static
    local-data: "local-service.domain.com. IN A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
    local-data-ptr: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx local-service.domain.com"
    forward-zone:
            name: "domain.com"
            forward-addr: 208.67.222.220
            forward-addr: 208.67.222.222
            forward-addr: 1.1.1.1
            forward-addr: 1.0.0.1
    forward-zone:
            name: "."
            forward-addr: 208.67.222.220
            forward-addr: 208.67.222.222
            forward-addr: 1.1.1.1
            forward-addr: 1.0.0.1
```

Thanks!

Comment: You would likely get you want by changing the `local-zone` from `static` to `transparent`.  From unbound.conf: If there is a match from local data, the query is answered. Otherwise if the query has a different name, the query is resolved normally. If the query is for a name given in localdata but no such type of data is given in localdata, then a noerror nodata answer is returned. If no local-zone is given local-data causes a transparent zone to be created by default.